# Remove Links on Excel after rendered from table2excel.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

Good day,

I am using table2excel.js to export my table into an excel file its working fine except that it still render links from the table..

my table

```
<table id='dataTable'>
    <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Item 1</a></td>
    <td>item 1 description</td>
    <td>item 1 price</td>
    <td>item 1 total</td>
    </tr>
</table>    


$('#table2xcel').click(function(){
  $("#dataTable").table2excel({
    exclude: ".xpage",
    name: "Worksheet Name",
    filename: "{{$excel_title}}" 
    });
});
```

Is there anyway I can convert an `<a href="#">Item 1</a>` into a regular text on excel?  Any Suggestion/Answers are much appreciated.. thank you..

Comment: So how does it come up in the excel file, do it come up like this : `<a href="#"> ...`??

Comment: thanks for passing by sir... in my case when using an actual link `file:///C:\adminx\reports\detailed_inventory_summary?departments[]=all&&categories[]=432` and my actual link was `www.reportxxx.com/adminx/reports.detailed_inventory_summary?departments[]=all&&categories[]=432` so basically links generated on excel file becomes useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
var x = $("#dataTable").clone();
$(x).find("tr td a").replaceWith(function(){
  return $.text([this]);
});
```

Just add this before you do the `$("#dataTable").table2excel()` function, but this case, it would be changed to `$(x).table2excel()`. It will replace the links with text.

Hope it helps

Comment: woah.. it really did the trick sir.. Thank you very much!!!   I also tried looking for the documentation on this plugin but it wasnt there :)

Answer (score 0):

I think:

```
$("#moduleTableApiId").table2excel({
    name: "Report Api Request",
    filename: "Report_Api_Request_" +new Date().getTime(),
    exclude_img: true,
    exclude_links: true,
    exclude_inputs: true
});
```

Hope it helps